# How do I list all running instances of an executable file on Linux?

Tags: linux, process

Is there a way to get the PIDs of all running instances of an executable file  on Linux?

Comment: `pidof <programname>`

Comment: Ipor Sircer, can you post this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a several ways to do this; you can list all processes and find ones that match the name of the executable you're interested in; or, you can list all running processes that have opened that specific executable file.

For example:

```
# list all processes, grep by filename
$ ps -ef | grep firefox
...(lots of output, need to cut/filter)...

# more specific, e.g., maybe there's also /opt/bin/firefox
$ ps -ef | grep /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
....
```

(Note: in the above example, you need to add `grep -v grep` if scripting this. Just adding this example for basic exploratory analysis.)

Example of built-in that does the same thing (basically):

```
$ pidof firefox
5915 5892 5851 5809 5753 5509

# more specific
$ pidof /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
5915 5892 5851 5809 5753 5509
```

This can also inadvertently list different executables with the same name, so some caution required. But it does have a really nice, terse output great for scripting.

Finally, a pretty robust option is to list open files (`lsof {program}`), and find the corresponding processes that are opening them (an executable file `{program}` is "open for reading" while it's running):

```
# note: sudo not always necessary, but might be
$ lsof /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
...
```